# Reusable function for getting mysql data

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to write a function which is able to return the sum of the `total_excl` column at the MySQL database. I’ve written a function, but its not reusable.

The function for the first quarter of the year.

```
public static function getFirstQuarterTotalExcl(){
    $first_day_of_1_quarter = date('Y-01-01');
    $last_day_of_1_quarter = date('Y-03-31');
    $query = "SELECT SUM(total_excl) FROM ".Zim_Properties::getTableName('Invoice')." WHERE invoice_date BETWEEN '$first_day_of_1_quarter' AND '$last_day_of_1_quarter'";
    $total = Zend_Registry::get('db')->fetchAll($query);
    return round($total[0]["SUM(total_excl)"]);
}
```

The second function for the second quarter of the year:

```
public static function getSecondQuarterTotalExcl(){
    $first_day_of_2_quarter = date('Y-04-01');
    $last_day_of_2_quarter = date('Y-06-30');
    $query = "SELECT SUM(total_excl) FROM ".Zim_Properties::getTableName('Invoice')." WHERE invoice_date BETWEEN '$first_day_of_2_quarter' AND '$last_day_of_2_quarter'";
    $total = Zend_Registry::get('db')->fetchAll($query);
    return round($total[0]["SUM(total_excl)"]);
}
```

As you can see. This code isn’t reusable which means that for every quarter of the year I have to write a new function. I want to make one function for every quarter. What should I do to make it reusable?

Comment: Send the dates / quarter as parameters and only use one function? Using php's date functions it would be pretty easy to determine the begin- and end dates using just the quarter number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I’ve written a function, but its not reusable.

No clear on what you mean here, but what about just setting the dates as part of the interface to the function like this:

```
public static function getQuarterTotalExcl($first_day_of_quarter,$last_day_of_quarter){
    // $first_day_of_2_quarter = date('Y-04-01');
    // $last_day_of_2_quarter = date('Y-06-30');
    $query = "SELECT SUM(total_excl) FROM ".Zim_Properties::getTableName('Invoice')." WHERE invoice_date BETWEEN '$first_day_of_quarter' AND '$last_day_of_quarter'";
    $total = Zend_Registry::get('db')->fetchAll($query);
    return round($total[0]["SUM(total_excl)"]);
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
$first_quarter_results = getQuarterTotalExcl(date('Y-01-01'), date('Y-03-31'));
$second_quarter_results = getQuarterTotalExcl(date('Y-04-01'), date('Y-06-30'));
$third_quarter_results = getQuarterTotalExcl(date('Y-07-01'), date('Y-09-30'));
$fourth_quarter_results = getQuarterTotalExcl(date('Y-10-01'), date('Y-12-31'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the two dates as parameters to your general function.
Something like:

```
function getQuarterTotalExcl($day1, $day2)
{
    $query = "SELECT SUM(total_excl) FROM ".Zim_Properties::getTableName('Invoice')." WHERE invoice_date BETWEEN '$day' AND '$day2'";
    $total = Zend_Registry::get('db')->fetchAll($query);
    return round($total[0]["SUM(total_excl)"]);
}
```